Change Apache2 default tmp directory to avoid full drive
Is it possible to modify apache2 default configuration to use another tmp folder instead /tmp? Let's say /filestore/temp.
Long story: I've some size restrictions on my /tmp drive and I would like to set an specific location for apache uploads. My application is in php but for a particulary feature (using webdav and chunks) apache is using tmp before moving to the final location set in php config. When I upload files via webdav, apache seems to use a modproxy+random_name folder inside tmp. With large files tmp becomes full and upload fails.
Of course, I tried to set php.ini values, but it seems is "caching" upload in /tmp before passing it to php
upload_tmp_dir="/filestore/temp"
sys_temp_dir = "/filestore/temp"

I tried to set TMPDIR on envvars like this (found it somewher in the internet but no success)
export TMPDIR=/filestore/temp

I would like to set it at envvars level or even better at vhost level. But I'm not sure if it is even possible. I'm using debian 11 apache2 apt package. Unit defined with PrivateTmp=true parameter. Not sure but it could be related also with mod_proxy or mod_proxy_fcgi
Also tried to disable PrivateTmp, but just moved same behaviour from /tmp/xxxx-apache2service-xxxxx to /tmp directly.

Disable the PrivateTmp=, but replace it with BindPaths= to explicitly select which location to mount onto the service's /tmp.
For example, BindPaths=/tmp/apache2-private:/tmp would be very similar to what PrivateTmp does. If you want to store the files elsewhere, do BindPaths=/filestore/temp/apache:/tmp or similar.
It doesn't seem like Apache2 honors TMPDIR, but if it would, then you'd also need to set it within the systemd service (using Environment=). Systemd does not understand the shell-specific 'export' keyword, even in EnvironmentFiles.
(Actually, I'm not entirely sure whether Apache stores any uploads in /tmp at all? I believe that's done entirely by PHP, so if you are using mod_php then the above suggestion will apply, but if you are using FPM then it's the 'php-fpm' service that needs to be changed instead.)

Some Linux distributions mount an in-memory tmpfs on /tmp (Debian 11 didn't yet, but had it as an option). If you have tons of spare RAM, you could enable tmp.mount to keep /tmp in-memory for the entire system; it is capped to "50% of physical RAM" at maximum. If you want to do this for Apache specifically, TemporaryFileSystem=/tmp could be used.

Thank you @u1686_grawity, just recently found that solution and works as you mention. Just to improve it a bit, I suggest to use native command to override Unit configuration "systemctl edit apache2.service"
[Service]
BindPaths=/filestore/apache_tmp:/tmp
PrivateTmp=false
The reload daemons and restart apache
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart apache2
The suggestion works with php-fpm as well. It's configured to use another location but this particular webdav/chunks cases use that temporary storage location.
